# Header to download file that contains semicolon in its filename

Tags: php, file, header, download, filenames

I already have a PHP code in order to force user download a file,
the code has worked well

the problem is, when user want to download a file that contains semicolon in its filename

for example
the code will be **success** if the file name XYZ.zip

but it **won't be success** if the file name aaaX;Y.zip (**read as** aaax [semicolon] Y [dot] zip)
when user download, the filename become aaaX

it's cut in first semicolon

```
<?php

$a=basename($_GET['fn']);
$sizepath =filesize(base64_decode($_GET['path']));

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$a); 
header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// load the file to send:

readfile(base64_decode($_GET['path']));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `urlencode()`, like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=us-ascii'en-us'".urlencode($a));
```

See [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231) for more information.

Comment: Thanks mate..but how if the filename has ' (quotes) ? I've tried your code it works in my previous problem

Comment: The `urlencode()` function encodes the quotes, so they should be fine.

Comment: @Igor - actually, your way is also correct. However, I haven't got double quotes to come through using either of the methods, at least not in Chrome on my Mac...

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $a . "\"" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Always be careful when giving the user control over a variable that ends up in file_get_contents(). This could result in the Path traversal vulnerability.

Comment: While you do make a good point, this answer would be better suited as a comment. Since you're new and do not have that ability yet, I would normally suggest that you expand on your point and provide a modified version of the OP's code that solves the original question in a safe way... But this question was asked 11 years ago so that's probably not necessary.